# Accessing AppDelegate.h from project - Beginner

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to access `AppDelegate.h` from another project. The project structure is given below:

> MYPROJECT
>
> |*_* OTHER PROJECT
>
> ```
>      |______OSAPPDELEGATE.H 
>
>      |______OSAPPDELEGATE.M
> ```
>
> |*_* APPDELEGATE.H
>
> |*_* APPDELEGATE.M

I need to import `#import AppDelegate.h` from `OsAppDelegate.h`. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the *Header Search Path* within Xcode to:

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/../OTHER PROJECT
```

and then simply:

```
#import "OSAPPDELEGATE.H"
```

better still, set the *Header Search Path* to:

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/..
```

and:

```
#import "OTHER PROJECT/OSAPPDELEGATE.H"
```

However if you are importing an app delegate from another project then you are most certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, i require the other way around. I need `#import AppDelegate.h` to be added in `OSAPPDELEGATE.H`

Comment: @sharonHwk Whatever. Once you've overcome the importing issue you'll be asking about link errors...

Comment: I have already added the header path. and i can import `OSAppDelegate.h` from my `AppDelegate.h` class. But i am unable to do it the otherway, which is import `AppDelegate.h` from the class `OSAppdelegate.h`. Help?

Comment: @sharonHwk Well I think my answer provides the gist of what is required (you might have change some values, but the idea is there).

Answer (score 0):

u can try doing this.. copy the methods of the app delegate into OsAppDelegate. not sure just try